# change range of letters in a specific column

Tags: bash, awk

I want to change in column 11 these characters

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-.\/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJ
```

for these characetrs:

```
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghi
```

so, if I have in column 11 `000@!`, it should be `PPP_@`. I tried `awk`:

```
awk '{a = gensub(/[@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghi]/, /[!\"\#$%&'\''()*+,-.\/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJ]/, "g", $11); print a }' file.txt
```

but it does not work...

Comment: Please edit the question and provide a sample file and the expected result.

Comment: It doesn't work because `gensub` does not work like `tr`. It replaces a regular expression with a (fixed) string, which may, however, contain parts of the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Perl.

```
perl -lane '$F[10] =~ y/!"#$%&'"'"'()*+,-.\/0-9:;<=>?@A-J/@A-Z[\\]^_`a-i/;
    print join(" ", @F)'
```

I am assuming by "column 11" you mean a string of several characters after the tenth run of successive whitespace, which is what the `-a` option splits on by default (basically to simulate Awk).  Unfortunately, changes to the array `@F` do not show up in the output directly, so you have to reconstruct the output line from (the modified) `@F`, which will normalize the field delimiter to just a single space.

Comment: As it happens, the range `,-.` in the source string happens to exactly match the characters `,`, `-`, and `.` (-:

Answer (score 2):

Just change `f = 2` to `f = 11`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    f = 2
    old = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-.\\/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJ"
    new = "@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\\]^_`abcdefghi"
    n = length(old)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        map[substr(old,i,1)] = substr(new,i,1)
    }
}
{
    n = length($f)
    newStr = ""
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        oldChar = substr($f,i,1)
        newStr = newStr (oldChar in map ? map[oldChar] : oldChar)
    }
    $f = newStr
    print
}

$ cat file
a 000@! b

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a PPP_@ b
```

Note that you have to escape `"`s and `\`s in strings.